# TLS/SSL - C# - how to execute queries against a remote sql server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssl

I have a winforms C# application which will have to send and receive information securely from a remote SQL Server.  At the moment I've just tested it with the database on my machine using the inbuilt classes e.g. SqlConnection.

I need to connecting my program to a remote SQL Server, execute queries against it.  Both computers are under my organisation's control, although the remote workers are off-site and may be using a 3G connection.

One option is to connect the two computers using a VPN, and then presumably the other computer is visible as if it was on the same network, then I can use my connection string as I have been doing so far, perhaps putting in the IP address. However the IT support people are grumbling about setting up VPNs.

**I have heard of TLS/SSL but never used this before.  Can i use it to send sql queries to a SQL Server directly?**

Comment: As long as your database server is open to the internet, you can connect to it from anywhere.  Of course, so can everyone else. Most IT folks would prefer to restrict access to boxes inside a firewall (or VPN tunnel).

Comment: we connect to our Sql and Oracle databases on a daily basis using `VPN`  so what's the problem and or issue.. do you have a knowledgeable `NetWork` team..?

Comment: We are a small company - 2 general IT/server/network guys and me (programmer).  They are talking about using DirectAccess, which looks promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SSL connectivity for SQL Server is encrypting the server socket connection.  With SQL Server, a temp certificate is created each time you start the SQL Server.  On the client side, you let the client accept any certificate, and this ensures your socket is encrypted (still open to Man in the Middle attack). You can also use your own signed certificate on both sides for the SSL connection.  The DBA's set this up, and there's nothing special to do on your end, other than possibly setting up your own certificate and changing the connection string.

[MSDN Using SSL Encryption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb879935(v=sql.110).aspx)

Typically, the datacenters (or host-host) are connected via private lan / VPN tunneling, which is also encrypted, and in this case, it would be a second layer of protection.  If you have a VPN, you could probably get away with the Servers built in SSL certificate.  That saves you the work of having to maintain the certificates each year.